# Jersey ParamConverter exceptions not handled by ExceptionMapper

Tags: exception, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Per title, exceptions thrown from a ParamConverter are NOT handled the way I expect.

With an ExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyException exception) {
        return Response.serverError().entity( "It triggered" ).build();
    }
}
```

and ParamConverter:

```
@Provider 
(boilerplate junk)
    @Override
    public DateTime fromString(String value) {
        throw new MyException("convert");
    }
```

It does NOT return the "It triggered" text in a 500 error, but rather a 404.

Anticipated question : Are both providers registered?

Yes - If I throw "MyException" from a resource (within 'regular' code) it works as expected. I can also convert see the stacktrace with the "convert" message.

Is there any way to make exceptions from ParamConverters be handled by the ExceptionMapper?

I am using jersey 2.3.1, along with spring-jersey, launched in a jetty container 9.1.0.RC0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seem from reading [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4976), the JAX-RS spec says the implementor should wrap unhandled exceptions in a `NotFoundException` (404) for `@QueryParam` and `@PathParam`, and from what I tested a 400, (I'm guessing `BadRequestException`) for `@FormParam`.

> "if the field or property is annotated with `@MatrixParam`, `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam` then an implementation MUST generate an instance of
>   `NotFoundException` (404 status) that wraps the thrown exception and no entity"

A couple ways I can see handling the exception, is to

1. Just handle it in the `ParamConverter`, e.g.

   ```
   return new ParamConverter<T>() {

       @Override
       public T fromString(String string) {
           try {
               return (T)new MyObject().setValue(string);
           } catch (MyException ex) {
               Response response = Response.serverError().entity("Boo").build()
               throw new WebApplicationException(response);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public String toString(T t) {
           return t.toString();
       }  
   };
   ```
2. Or just have your exception extend [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), and return the `Response` there. e.g.

   ```
   public class MyException extends WebApplicationException {

       public MyException(String message) {
           super(Response.serverError().entity(message).build());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I must say, I am really surprised by this behaviour, but in the end it makes sense to me. The query params are part of the URL, and they cannot be resolved, the URL is invalid.

We had the problem for parsing dates (YYYY-MM-DD) as query params. In our custom query param converter, we throwed an `DateTImeParseException` which in fact was then wrapped into the NotFoundException. To resolve the 'issue' we are now throwing a custom exception which inherits from WebApplicationException with a custom mapper. :)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same behavior in Jersey 2.26.

Any Exception that extends RuntimeException gets mapped to a ParamException, which is itself a sublcass of WebApplicationException. 
Assuming your MyException extends RuntimeException, it's not getting caught because your ExceptionMapper only handles MyException.

Regarding the Jersey docs saying to throw a NotFoundException: I would argue a 404 does not apply when a queryParam can't be converted. A BadRequestException seems more appropriate. And also,  I can't see anything unique in the Jersey frame work when a NotFoundException is thrown besides setting the response code

To get exceptions thrown from a ParamConverter end up in an ExceptionMapper, you'll have to have your ExceptionMapper catching a more global exception, like Throwable.

Another answer suggests returning a WebApplicationException. This should be a fine solution but will NOT work if the Response object has an entity. See here: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3716